# Representation theory via examples.

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

I have referred to some books on representation theory and somehow I cannot get a feel out of this subject. I guess the main reason is every book talks big and lacks examples.

I am looking for best source (online notes/book/ video lectures) which deals with finding all irreducible representations of various groups and finding character tables for various group and thus teach representation theory i.e. via examples.

Thanks!

Comment: How about Fulton and Harris?

Comment: @anomaly It mainly focus on Lie theory. I need an easier/more introductory reference than that.

Comment: Have you looked through the "Related" questions shown to the right on the desktop version of this Question?  There are a number of examples and text references to be found there.

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind? The standard first course in representation theory deals with complex representations of a few small groups, the symmetric groups, compact Lie groups, and so on. There's a very cursory treatment in Artin's "Algebra," but that's probably not going to be very satisfying. What are you trying to get out of specific examples that wouldn't be covered elsewhere? Most books beyond the undergrad level don't focus on, or even have many, examples.

Comment: you can look at barry simon's book by AMS

Comment: The discussion in Dummit & Foote's *Abstract Algebra* is not too technical and has (as usual) detailed examples of classifying representations of finite groups (mostly over $\Bbb C$) and computing character tables.

Comment: How about Representations and characters of groups written by Gordon James and Martin Liebeck?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned this is one of the best reference for representation theory http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/repb.pdf . it has a lot of examples, exercises and historical insights.